# OAuth2 refresh_token grant

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization

I`ve created an OAuth2 authorization in my application, but still i don`t understand how refresh token grant works.

I`ve managed to generate and store refresh_token with password grant_type.

(in:

```
public async Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
```

)

And in result of first /token request, the response is following:

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiasFzI1NiJ9.eyJyb2xlIjoibWVtYmVyIiwidW5pcXVlX25hbWUiOiIyIiwiZ2l2ZW5fbmFtZSI6IkpvaG4iLCJmYW1pbHlfbmFtZSI6IlNtaXRoIiwiRXhlcmNpc2UiOiJBbWF6b24gRXhlcmNpc2UiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjUxMDAvdG9rZW4iLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjUxMDAvdG9rZW4iLCJleHAiOjE1MDI3MDg1ODYsIm5iZiI6MTUwMjcwNDk4Nn0.H7GOcSiqp9H53ckx5_3anwEEqhXCk_UAlOcorM_2vgs",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "refresh_token": "bf183e7d-b120-475f-881b-91a32d344e58"
}
```

But then, when I create another /token POST:

```
 [{"key":"grant_type","value":"refresh_token","description":""},
    {"key":"refresh_token","value":"00a4d77d-52a7-4b32-aa8c-6c7ad1d65696","description":""}]
```

I have no idea how to handle this refresh_token in order to create and send new access token. 
There are many things that happen auto-magically, what confuses me even more.

Should this management be in :

```
public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
```

in CustomOAuthProvider?

if no, then which method should check incoming request; and how to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood `ValidateClientAuthentication` method. Its only for CLIENT (ex. API, Website, WPF client) not for USER validation purposes.

I've managed to do following:
Validation logic is correctly in

```
Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
```

Another thing is that, I`ve used custom header parameters instead of default (magically binded i think :) ) 'password', 'username' and 'scope'

Now I have access to every of them inside `OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext` object without making weird hacks with `context.OwinContext.Set("", ob)...`

TL;DR
ValidateClientAuthentication for Validating Client (Api, websites etc.)

GrantResourceOwnerCredentials to verify if given credentials are correct